# C# interface function definition concrete implementation

Tags: c#, generics, interface, implementation

How do I implement the function defined in the interface below? When I implemented in VS2010 like I have below. MyType gets greyed out and it doesn't recongise the type anymore? thanks!

```
public interface IExample
{
  T GetAnything<T>();
}

public class MyType
{
  //getter, setter here
}

public class Get : IExample
{
 public MyType GetAnything<MyType>()
 {      ^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^
   MyType mt = new MyType();
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    /* all greyed out !!*/
 }
}
```

Comment: This has an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/4068) feeling to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a generic `interface IExample<T>` and then implement it using the concrete type `class Get : IExample<MyType>` as in the example below.

```
public interface IExample<T> where T : new()
{
    T GetAnything();
}

public class Get : IExample<MyType>
{
    public MyType GetAnything()
    {
        MyType mt = new MyType();
        return mt;
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The method's type parameter `T` hides the interface's type parameter `T`; they have the same name, but they are independent.

Comment: @phoog yes, thanks. But I think you can drop the method's type parameter. Updated my code example accordingly.

Comment: you forgot a where T: new() on your interface declaration;)

Comment: Yes, I think that's what you intended.  It remains to be seen whether the OP is trying to store homogenous `IExample<T>`s in a single collection; that's usually what people want, and of course it complicates matters somewhat.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Already added a few minutes ago. But thanks anyway. These are the details I always miss when writing code without the compiler. Once pasted in VS, it becomes obvious.

Comment: @DennisTraub especially if you have ReSharper

Comment: In the interface what is the difference between  IExample{T GetAnything<T>();} vs  IExample {T GetAnything();}

Answer (score 1):

Dennis' answer looks like what you *want* but just in case it isn't, in order to get *your* code working, you can do this but I'm not sure how much value this really has...

```
public class Get : IExample
{
    public T GetAnything<T>()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public void X()
{
    var get = new Get();
    var mt = get.GetAnything<MyType>();
}
```